# NDTS Connections in two-site domain

Tags: active-directory

A quick check on best practice here.
I have two sites, each with two DC's. Site A is the bigger/more important of the two, but Site B does have some services running there.

I inherited the domain and I see in Sites & Services manual NDTS connections from each DC in Site A to each DC in Site B. There is a single inter-site transport setup.

My question - should I delete the manual connections, particularly those across the WAN, and let the inter-site link take care of the replication?

Thanks.

Comment: `should I delete the manual connections, particularly those across the WAN, and let the inter-site link take care of the replication?` I would. It can be done one at a time. Typically this means that only one DC will replicate between sites. You may want to check if Site Link Change Notification is enabled. If, ensure it is enabled in the new connections. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/configuring-change-notification-on-a-manually-created/ba-p/400188